# How to change a widget's font style without knowing the widget's font family/size?

Tags: python, user-interface, fonts, tkinter

Is there a way to change a *Tkinter* widget's font style without knowing the widget's font family and font size?

Use case: We create our UI using standard *Tkinter* widgets (*Label*, *Entry*, *Text*, etc). While our application runs we may want to dynamically change the font style of these widgets to bold and/or italics using the `.config()` method. Unfortunately there appears to be no way to specify a font spec without specifying the font's family and size.

The following are examples of what we'd like to do, but neither of these examples work:

```
widget.config(font='bold')
```

or

```
widget.config(font=( None, None, 'bold' ))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `font = '-weight bold'` be the simplest solution?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's a much better way than using `.config()` to change your application font, especially if your goal is to change the font for a whole group of widgets or all widgets.

One of the really great features of Tk is the notion of "named fonts", which are implemented as objects in tkinter. The beauty of named fonts is, if you update the font, all widgets that use that font will automatically get updated. So, configure your widgets once to use a font object, then you can update all widgets at once simply by changing the configuration of the font object.

Here's a quick example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        # create a custom font
        self.customFont = tkinter.font.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)

        # create a couple widgets that use that font
        buttonframe = tk.Frame()
        label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world", font=self.customFont)
        text = tk.Text(root, width=20, height=2, font=self.customFont)

        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        text.insert("end","press +/- buttons to change\nfont size")

        # create buttons to adjust the font
        increase_font = tk.Button(root, text="+", command=self.increase_font)
        decrease_font = tk.Button(root, text="-", command=self.decrease_font)

        increase_font.pack(in_=buttonframe, side="left")
        decrease_font.pack(in_=buttonframe, side="left")

        root.mainloop()

    def increase_font(self):
        '''Make the font 2 points bigger'''
        size = self.customFont['size']
        self.customFont.configure(size=size+2)

    def decrease_font(self):
        '''Make the font 2 points smaller'''
        size = self.customFont['size']
        self.customFont.configure(size=size-2)

app=App()
```

If you don't like that approach, or if you want to base your custom font on the default font, or if you're just changing one or two fonts to denote state, you can use `font.actual` to get the actual size of a font for a given widget. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")
font = tkinter.font.Font(font=label['font'])
print(font.actual())
```

When I run the above I get the following output:

```
{'family': 'Lucida Grande', 
 'weight': 'normal', 
 'slant': 'roman', 
 'overstrike': False, 
 'underline': False, 
 'size': 13}
```

Comment: Bryan: Thank you very much! The named font capability looks very handy - your demo reminds me of how one can resize fonts in a browser. The ability to do the same in a desktop client would be impressive. The .actual() method gives me the information I needed to solve my short term task. A note to readers of this post: .actual() returns font height in pixels vs. points. To use this value when constructing a font tuple, one must multiply by -1 because Tkinter font tuples expect font sizes in pixels to be negative values (positive values represent font sizes in points).

Comment: Very nicely explained. Thank you Bryan. I was planning to do what the OP wanted, but I upgraded to the named fonts rather than doing repeated changes of local fonts.

Comment: In Python 3 it's `from tk import font` instead of `import tkFont`.

Comment: in Python 3 it's still not working. do I have to rename "font" in the examples or something too?

Comment: @Gabriel: No. Just change the imports. See updated answer.

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 37):

Even shorter for just one Label:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

# font="-weight bold" does your thing
example = Label(root, text="This is a bold example.", font="-weight bold")
example.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can defiantly confirm this works. Seems like the most simplest solution (?)

Comment: Note: this doesn't do what the OP actually wants, which is to change the font attributes of an existing object.  If  you create a label in some other font and then configure the size with `font="-weight bold"`, you may end up with a different font family. All this does is create a bold label in the default font, not set an existing font or label to bold.

Comment: `self.myLabel.config(fg='black', font='-weight bold')` This works with an existing label!

Comment: @GabrielStaples:  yes, but if the label had been previously configured to use a different font, it wouldn't use that font and set it bold, it would just change it to the default font with the bold setting.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a named font, you can use a couple statements to get what you want:

```
import tkFont
wfont = tkFont.nametofont(widget['font'])
wfont.config(weight='bold')
```

**Edited** to incorporate B. Oakley's comment.

Comment: Corfman: this will fail unless the font is a named font. For example, define a widget with a font like `("Helvetica",12,"bold")`  and your code will fail.

Comment: Brandon: Thank you for your help. I'm sure I will find a use for the nametofont technique in the future.

Comment: To not change named font in whole app but just for the widget you need copy it: 
`wfont = tkFont.nametofont(widget['font']).copy()
wfont.config(weight='bold')
widget['font'] = wfont`

Answer (score 7):

just use the basic attributes of a particular widget, suppose you want to change the font of a label. You can use the following syntax:

```
mlabel = Label(text="Your text", font=("Name of your font",size))
```

this code works for python 3.4

Comment: The point of the question is that the user does not know the "Name of your font".

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `None` won't necessarily change the attribute of the widget's current font and

Comment: @BryanOakley what are you trying to say? `Label(font=(None, size))` changes the font size (at least on my system).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the question is about how to change a font attribute (eg: just the size) on an existing widget or existing font. If you do `label.configure(font=(None, size)` it won't just change the font size, it will also change the font family.

Comment: @BryanOakley you're right, the question assumes existing widgets. I've landed on the page from google and `(None, size)` works for my use case (specify the font size without specifying Label's font family).

Answer (score 2):

To get the default font without touching or having a widget you can use the generic name of the default font.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter
import tkinter.font  # Python3!

tkinter.Tk()
default_font = tkinter.font.Font(font='TkDefaultFont')
print(default_font.actual())
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is really old, but I am still going to answer for the sake of people from google.

If you just want to make the text a bit bigger, you can do `font=15`. Note this seems to always set the font size to 15, no matter what number is entered.

If want an exact size and have not changed the font, you can do `font=('TkDefaultFont', 15)`.

(`'TkDefaultFont'` is the default font for tkinter)

You can use either of these in the parameters of the widget on creation, or later with `.config()`.

---

Works in python 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

To boil much of the above information down to a single code snippet:

```
lbl = ttk.Label(blah, blah)   # Make a label
font = tkFont(lbl['font'])    # Get its font
font.config(weight='bold')    # Modify font attributes
lbl['font'] = font            # Tell the label to use the modified font
```

This permits font attributes to be changed independent of the font in use (so long as the font supports that attribute).

You can also do this on the fly, to create truly nauseating font effects.

Comment: this code will fail because `tkFont` is a module, not a class. Even if `tkFont` did what the author thinks, the code can still fail because the font from the label could be one of a couple different formats, neither of which can be directly used to create a font. Finally, the comments in the code are wrong -- you aren't "getting its font" and "modifying its attributes", you are creating a whole new font.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's been quite some time since this Q was asked, I recently had to implement a solution to this, which I thought worth sharing.  The function widget_font_config(...) runs on Python 2 and 3.

In essence, the "current value" of the widget's font is grabbed, modified, and then put back.  Named fonts are supported, and the default **inplace_f** value of **True** means that named fonts will be preserved and modified in place.  But the flag can also be set to **False**, which will cause a named font to be replaced with a different named font, in case the user does not wish for the changes in the font of the widget to percolate to all other widgets which use the named font.

```
def widget_font_config(widget, inplace_f=True, **kwargs):
    import sys
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        import tkFont as tk_font
    else:
        import tkinter.font as tk_font
    inplace_f = kwargs.pop('inplace', inplace_f)
    font = None    
    if widget and 'font' in widget.config():
        current_font = widget.cget('font') #grabs current value
        namedfont_f = False
        try:
            font = tk_font.nametofont(current_font)
            namedfont_f = True
        except:
            font = current_font
        if namedfont_f and inplace_f:
            font.config(**kwargs)
        else:
            font_d = tk_font.Font(font=font).actual()
            font_d.update(**kwargs)
            font = tk_font.Font(**font_d)
            widget.config(font=font)
        widget.update_idletasks()
    return font

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    pyVers = sys.version_info[0] # .major
    if pyVers == 2:
        import Tkinter as tk, tkFont as tk_font
    else:
        import tkinter as tk, tkinter.font as tk_font
    def go():
        print(widget_font_config(root.label,  slant='roman', underline=1).actual())
        print(widget_font_config(root.button, overstrike=1).actual())
    root = tk.Tk()
    font_s = 'Courier 20 italic'
    font_d = dict(family='Courier', size=10, weight='normal', slant='italic')
    font = tk_font.Font(**font_d)
    root.label = tk.Label(text='Label {}'.format(font_s), font=font_s)
    root.label.pack()
    root.button = tk.Button(text='Button {}'.format(font), font=font, command=go)
    root.button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I should mention that this works for all fonts: named fonts, font tuples, font descriptors, etc.