# Control Font in tkMessageBox

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I would to like to control the font of the text on a tkMessageBox but I can't see any reference of such a stuff. Is it only implemented in Tkinter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure the font for just dialog boxes by doing the following:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
r = Tk()
r.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Helvetica 12')
tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='Hello')
```

(Only the option_add invocation is modified from the accepted answer.)

Comment: Is it possible to change the messagebox width too?

Answer (score 2):

The following works here. You will need to change the second argument of option to the font type and font size you want.

```
 from Tkinter import *
 import tkMessageBox
 r = Tk()
 r.option_add('*font', 'Helvetica -12')
 tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='Hello')
```

You may have to call `r.option_clear()` to clear it afterwards.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072150/python-tkinter-how-to-change-a-widgets-font-style-without-knowing-the-widgets) for more information about setting the font of other Tkinter widgets.

This doesn't work with tkMessageBox because tkCommonDialog doesn't take the font option.

Answer (score 0):

option_add may only work for linux operating systems, but you can control font, where the lines wrap, and the width of the box:

```
    root.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Helvetica 24')
    root.master.option_add('*Dialog.msg.width', 34)
    root.master.option_add("*Dialog.msg.wrapLength", "6i")
```