# How to set font of a messagebox with Python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using the simple message-boxes provided in `tkinter` and I'm wondering if there's any way to change the font.

This is the general idea of what I want, but the `font=` option doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmsg

_root = Tk()
_root.withdraw()
tkmsg.showinfo(
    "Info",
    "Some monospaced text",
    font=("Monospace", 15)
)
_root.destroy()
```

Is there any way to change the font or do I have to use a custom dialog?

Comment: You should make your own tkinter.Toplevel() dialog to customize fonts. Oh, and use tkinter.font.Font() instances.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam I don't think there's a way to use Toplevel() to set fonts. Am I missing something?

Comment: As in answer of Lucas Sabião, you should put a Label widget into your toplevel dialog window. You can customize font of the Label.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347645/control-font-in-tkmessagebox

Answer (score -5, accepted):

<s>you can't.
write your own messagebox using the toplevel widgted (tkinter.Toplevel()) and label!</s>

Something like this (from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Label(master, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

i hope it helps!

Edit: This is a very old answer, 3 years later someone said it's possible:
[Control Font in tkMessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347645/control-font-in-tkmessagebox)

Comment: Wrong; you can. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347645/control-font-in-tkmessagebox

Answer (score 3):

See here for how to change the dialog box text: [Control Font in tkMessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347645/control-font-in-tkmessagebox)

In short (copied verbatim from the link above):

> You can configure the font for just dialog boxes by doing the following:
>
> ```
> from Tkinter import *
> import tkMessageBox
> r = Tk()
> r.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Helvetica 12')
> tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='Hello')
> ```

Be sure to call `r.option_clear()` to set the font back to normal afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me in Python 3.4.4 (even after changing MessageBox for the newer messagebox capitalization). And when I did r.option_add('*font', 'Courier 12') it changed all the fonts except the messagebox fonts.

Comment: @CuriousMarc Nor for me in Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default font for captions:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import font
root = tk.Tk() 
font1 = font.Font(name='TkCaptionFont', exists=True)
font1.config(family='courier new', size=20)
mb.showinfo(message='Hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own messagbox. Tkinter invoke system dialog for Windows or Mac and genetate dialogs for Linux. In all cases is imposible change Tkinter dialogs.

Comment: See here, you can change the dialogs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347645/control-font-in-tkmessagebox