# Why can you adjust font size for messagebox in Python 2 but not in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, messagebox

I was looking to add a simple message box to a program and it looks like you can't adjust the font size in python 3. That's annoying but not too bad - I'll just make my own window and get over it. What I don't understand is why the font was adjustable in python 2 but is no longer adjustable in python 3?

Example message box in python 3:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def Help(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("Window title", "Sample text")

test_button = Button(root, text="Test Button", font=("Helvetica", 25), command=self.Help)
test_button.grid(row = 2, column =0)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a question addressing font adjustment in python 2: [Control Font in tkMessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347645/control-font-in-tkmessagebox?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And here is a question addressing the *lack* of font adjustment in python 3: [How to set font of a messagebox with Python tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324103/how-to-set-font-of-a-messagebox-with-python-tkinter)

Can anyone explain the apparent loss in functionality? Why would we lose this option in a seemingly improved version of python?

EDIT: It looks like the solution applied in Python 2 will work on Linux machines running python 3. The issue seems to be limited to Windows operating systems (tested on Windows 7 and Windows 10).

Comment: seems on Windows, the messagebox dialog is "native" https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705264/3353857