# how to change font size of messages inside messagebox.showinfo(message='Hello') in tkinter python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make displayed message fonts bigger for certain messages when it get displayed so that its easier for eyes to read than standard size. I checked on past post regarding this issue and couldn't found any answers that helps. I found answer using r.option_add but it seems not to have any effect on windows. If any one has gone through this issue and have suggestion/answer to fix this problem i would be thankful to everyone who put their time and effort on it. Thank you.

Code i found on previous posts or link: https://grokbase.com/t/python/tkinter-discuss/054chdx51f/font-control-in-tkmessagebox

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

r = Tk()

r.option_add('*font', 'Helvetica-18')

messagebox.showinfo(message='Hello')

Answer (score 1):

In the [Tcler's wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tk%5FmessageBox) it says: "With recent versions, the Windows messageBox is "native"...", which as far as I can tell means it's using a windows component and you can't change the mesage box font.

You could try to make your own custom dialog with the help of tkinters simpledialog. Have a look at [effbot: Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: Thank you figbeam, i will have to go through dialog windows and give a try. Thank you for your input.