# Change Text Widget font in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fonts, text-widget

I'm making a function that will increase the text widget's size by 1 every time it's called.
I cannot find a way to find the current font size of the widget.
I need something like:

```
textEntry.configure(font=(fontSize=fontSize+1))
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4072150/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley this is far neater than my answer - outstanding work, as always.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution but it works for all fonts and can contain any valid font parameter(s).

```
def increaseSize():
    font = textEntry.cget('font')       #get font information
    info = font.split(' ')              #split it into chunks

    #find the font size entry
    for i in info:
        if i.isdigit():
            size = int(i)
            textEntry.config(font=font.replace(i, str(size + 1)))
            break
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly for what I'm doing.

Comment: This will only work if you define the font as a tuple. That's not the only way to define fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `.config()` on a widget without any parameters, it returns a dictionary containing the current configuration. So, `textEntry.config()` would get you a dictionary for the `textEntry` widget, and `textEntry.config()['font']` would get you a tuple of values relating to your font settings. Assuming your `font` settings consist **only** of a size parameter (e.g. `font=10`)

```
curSize = int(textEntry.config()['font'][-1])
```

would get you an integer containing the current font size

Comment: My font consists of a family and a size.